# PySpark - For every DF1 row apply a random 40% of the DF2 row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 DFs. For every row in DF1, I wanted to join(cross join) random 40% of the data from DF2.
For example, for the first row in DF1, I would take 40% of data from DF2 and do a cross join between them. The same way 2nd row from DF1 and cross join with 40% of DF2 data. Then produce the output.

DF1

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

DF2

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | kk |
| y | zz |
| z | mm |
| l | gg |

For every DF1 row cross joining with a random 40% of the DF2 row.
output

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x | kk |
| 1 | a | l | gg |
| 2 | b | z | mm |
| 2 | b | x | kk |
| 3 | c | x | kk |
| 3 | c | y | zz |

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.sample` to get a 40% sample (based on `rowcount * 0.4`) of `DF2` and then `crossJoin` this onto `DF1`.
Couple of caveats:

- This will be always the same sample (e.g. random slice based on a given seed)
- Taking a new sample for each row would constitute a row-based operation (i.e. you'd likely need a UDF/Pandas UDF) and the performance would be atrocious
- You should be setting the seed for your sample function explicitly to have reproducible results